# Пользовательская клавиатура

Tags: android

Как реализовать пользовательскую клавиатуру для программы? Андроидом занимаюсь недавно, пишу матричный калькулятор, не устраивает, что при ландшафтной ориентации клава занимает много места. Хочу сделать аккуратную клавиатуру с двумя строками (в ландшафтной ориентации с одной).

Comment: простой удобный пример для тех кому надо что то не сильно сложное https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы реализовать пользовательскую клавиатуру, нужно создать свой метод ввода: [Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html). Пример есть в SDK - это SoftKeyboard. Его можно использовать как базу для своей клавиатуры.