# Принудительно вставить текст во внешнее поле

Tags: java, android, nfc

Есть фокус на поле, в браузере или блокноте. Когда я подношу `nfc`, нужно принудительно вставить текст метки в фокусное поле. Я знаю, как считать `nfc` метку и занести ее в буфер. Но как принудительно вставить этот текст в внешнее для моего приложения выделенное поле? В возможностях `clipboard manager`, к сожалению, я ничего не нашел. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? может эмулировать функции клавиатуры?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что тебе надо реализовать кастомную клавиатуру. А может метод ввода. Посмотри [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/152307/178988).